# Was the coverup of the fall of Harvey Dent from the comics?

Tags: dc, batman, canon

In [Nolan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Nolan)'s Batman movies ([2nd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_%28film%29) and [3rd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Rises)),

1. Harvey Dent falls from glory
2. Batman takes the blame
3. Commissioner Gordon covers it all up.

Was that whole taking the fall for Dent and coverup from the comics?
Or was this something added to the universe in Nolan's movies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: Nope. Original story.

Long answer: No, but it did draw heavily on a few comics that mirrored parts of the movie, most relevant to Dent's story being [Batman: The Long Halloween](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3a_The_Long_Halloween). In it, Dent, Batman and Gordon team up to go after mob boss Falcone, ending in Falcone's death by Dent's deranged hands.

Comment: excellent answer, and I'll add "Batman: Dark Victory" (sequel to The Long Halloween) as another source book, though clearly not to the extent of The Long Halloween.

Answer (score 3):

That story line was original with Nolan AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Nolan story element. Batman in the movies, is a far more public figure than he every is in his own comics.

During the Year One/Long Halloween era stories, Batman essentially is still an urban legend at best, with Gotham only having two or three previous major vigilantes that no one every remembers.